# Play 2.5.12 Java - Missing HttpContext when replacing deprecated GlobalSettings.OnStart

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, transactional

I'm trying to migrate from Play 2.3 to 2.5 but I have an issue on replacing the GlobalSettings.OnStart method.
In my old Global class that was extending GlobalSettings, in the onStartMethod I was initialising the Global Config and reading basic things from the DB.
I have created a new class and I m moving the code from the onStart method to the constructor of this one as mentioned in the doc.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PluginsToModules

I'm doing the binding as eagerSingleton from an AbstractModule. The class is correctly started but I keep getting the error:

> GlobalBootstrapModule.configure:20 - Binding
>
> OnStartConfig.:35 - Global...on start
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPAApi.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on this thread.

This is my code:

New class to replace onStart

```
public class OnStartConfig implements StartConfigInterface{

private final JPAApi jpaApi;

@Inject
public OnStartConfig(Application application, JPAApi jpa){
   this.jpaApi = jpa;
   Logger.debug("Global...on start");

   jpaApi.withTransaction( ()-> {
        GlobalConfiguration.aggregationCriteria = AggregationCriterion.getAll();
    });
}
```

The interface I'm extending is just an empty placeholder.

AbstractModule used for the binding:

```
public class GlobalBootstrapModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {

Logger.debug("Binding");
bind(StartConfigInterface.class).to(OnStartConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();

    }
}
```

And I have enabled the module in the application.conf file:

```
play {
   modules {
   enabled += modules.GlobalBootstrapModule
   }
}
```

I suppose the problem is due to the lack of HttpContext. Where can I grab it from during the initialisation?
Any help would be hugely appreciated